# append() in jquery appending to right of tr?

Tags: jquery

I've got this:

```
$(".TempAddLineItem").live('click', function() { 
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).closest("tr").append("<tr><td>row creating</td></tr>");
        //$(this).append("<tr><td>row creating</td></tr>");
        $this.prev('.AddLineItem').click();
        return false;
    });
```

The issue Im having is it appears to append to a `<td>` rather then a `<tr>` that is
in my asp.net gridview, after the append it looks like it adds a column rather then a row ???

Comment: can you add your markup here? or host it on jsfiddle or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) indeed inserts content inside the element. You're looking for [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td>row creating</td></tr>");
```

**EDIT:** If you want to get a reference to the new table row, you can invert the logic and use [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$("<tr><td>row creating</td></tr>").hide()
                                   .insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"))
                                   .fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 2):

You want [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/), not [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

> ### .after
>
> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.
>
> ### .append
>
> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: Cool one last question - is there a way to get a reference to this new row so I can fadeItOut or fadeItIn?  The newly created row that is...

Comment: You could make an element first: `var $newRow = $('<tr> etc'); $(this).closest("tr").append($newRow);`

Answer (score 1):

the code apends it to the tr tag. so something like that is the result:

```
<tr>
    <td>orig</td>
    <tr><td>row creating</td></tr>
</tr>
```

you have to use after()